# How to update static resources in Spring MVC without rebuilding?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources

I have a classic Spring MVC project where my resource files are put in the directory:

webapp -- resources -- js

webapp -- resources -- css

I also use:

```
<!--declare resources-->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

My question what do I need to config so that every time I update the css & js files the changes appear when I refresh the page ?

Right now I have to rebuild the project each time a change is made so that the war file is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to split your project in two:
- a front-end module
- a classic war module

This way, you can set up whatever front-end build tool you want to (grunt, gulp, etc) and ship all your optimized in a web JAR as a dependency of your war module.

And of course, this way you can serve resources directly from disk, no need to redeploy your server each time. There's [a full example here](https://github.com/bclozel/spring-resource-handling).

Comment: Using the Spring Boot embedded container makes this drastically easier.